MySQL logging verbosity level not taking effect
Our MySQL configs are as below:
@@version - 5.7.23
@@log_warnings - 2
@@log_error_verbosity - 3

However, the notes getting logged are not verbose enough and like below
2024-09-26T08:56:39.519313Z 6624396 [Note] 
2024-09-26T08:56:39.519423Z 6622841 [Note] 
2024-09-26T08:56:39.519471Z 6624696 [Note] 
2024-09-26T08:56:39.519532Z 6623360 [Note] 
2024-09-26T08:56:39.552200Z 6624397 [Note]

The mysql user has required write permissions on the log file and the system has enough space available.

@@log_error_verbosity effects on the logginig events types and not on their format/verbosity.

Some settings (perhaps these) do not take effect until mysqld is restarted.

@Akina so what configuration is needed for getting more verbose messages?

@RickJames mysqld was restarted after updating these configs

What is the output of
show global variables like '%verbosity%';

3 means -
3   ERROR, WARNING, INFORMATION
It seems that you are getting Note, which is correct in error logs.
